# Moodle courses: how to add bulk upload capability for manager role?

Tags: moodle

On Moodle 3.5, my managers (role) have not the menu to make a courses bulk upload with the csv file.

I need to give them that capability. (Moodle's guide advices [this capability](https://docs.moodle.org/36/en/Capabilities/moodle/course:upload)). I tried to set managers' roles but I didn't found that capability between all of them.

How to add bulk upload capability for manager role?

Answer (score 1):

That's a different capability, the capability you need is `tool/uploadcourse:uploadcourses`

See `/admin/tool/uploadcourse/settings.php`

Comment: How to add that capability to managers? It's not in my list